# How do I prevent transform hover from overlapping with navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

Sorry this code is extremely long but I just posted whole thing so that you guys can have an easier time answering I guess.. The question is in the title, how do I prevent my enlarged container when hovered over container from overlapping my navigation bar like in picture below. I want it behind the navigation bar but still enlarged. The class that I'm doing the hover on is "enlarge" for easier finding.

Thanks guys.

```
  margin-top:100px;
}
.normal{
  font-style:normal;
}

#intro-container{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3,400px);
  grid-column-gap:200px;
  margin-top:30px;
  justify-content:center;
}

#header-image{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  grid-column:2/3;
}
#vid1{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
#vid2{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}

.navbar{
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed; /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
  top: 0; /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
  width: 100%;   
}
.navbar a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
.navbar a {
  float:right;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  display:block;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding: 30px 30px;
}

body{
  background-color: #c19f97;
}

#intro{
  padding-top:50px;
text-align:center;
}

#email-container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
}

#video{
  text-align:center;
}

#email-input{
  width:348px;
  border-radius:3px;
}

#email-submit{
  background-color:#7e544b;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color:white;
  margin:10px 14px;
  border-radius:4px;
}
#email-submit:hover{
  background:#c4a49c;
  transform:scale(1.02);
}

#features-container{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:400px 400px 400px;
  grid-column-gap:200px;
  justify-content:center;
}

#delivery-truck-container{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  flex-direction:column;
  border-style:solid;
  padding:40px;
  border-radius:10px;
  font-style:oblique;
}
#delivery-truck-container:hover {
  background:#d6c0ba;
}

#clothes-container{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  flex-direction:column;
  border-style:solid;
  padding:40px;
  border-radius:10px;
  font-style:oblique;
}
#clothes-container:hover{
  background:#d6c0ba
}

#credit-card-container{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  flex-direction:column;
  border-style:solid;
  padding:40px;
  border-radius:10px;
  font-style:oblique;
}
#credit-card-container:hover{
  background:#d6c0ba;
}
#delivery-truck{
  height:200px;
}

#clothes{
  height:200px;
}

#credit-card{
  height:200px;
}

.enlarge:hover{
  transform:scale(1.05);
}




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <div class="navbar" id="navigationbar">
    <a href="#Features">Features</a>
    <a href="#intro">Introduction</a>
    <a href="#prices">Prices</a> <br><br><br>
  </div>
    
  <div id="main-container">
    
    <h1 id="header"><center>Company name</center></h1>
  <div id="intro-container">
    <div id="vid1"><iframe id ="vid1" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/nSDgHBxUbVQ" width=300px height=300px></iframe></div>
    <div id="header-image"><img id="image1" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/circle-business-logo-company-name-260nw-626261534.jpg" alt="company-logo"></div>
    <div id="vid2"><iframe id="vid2" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YdYwICNPDwI" width=300px height=300px></iframe></div><br><br>
  </div>
    
    
    
  
    <center><h1>Lorem ipsum</h1></center><br>
  <div id="features-container">
      
      <div class="enlarge" id="delivery-truck-container">
        <div id="delivery-truck-pic">
      <img class="pic" id="delivery-truck" src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Share/icon/ultraviolet/Ecommerce/delivery1600.png" alt="delivery-truck">
        </div>
        <div id="clothes-content">
          <center><h1 class="normal">Lorem ipsum do</h1></center>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.     </div>
    </div>
      
      <div class="enlarge" id="clothes-container">
        <div id="clothes-pic">
      <img class="pic1" id="clothes" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/106/106020.png" alt="clothes">
        
        </div>
        <div id="clothes-content">
          <center><h1 class="normal">Lorem ipsum do</h1></center>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
      
      <div class="enlarge" id="credit-card-container">
        <div class="pic" id="credit-card-pic">
      <img class="pic" id="credit-card" src="https://loanssos.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/credit-card.png" alt="credit-card">
      </div>
        <div id="credit-card-content">
          <center><h1 class="normal">Lorem ipsum do</h1></center>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div id="email-container">
      <form action="https://www.freecodecamp.org/email-submit">
        <div id="email">
        <input id="email-input" type="email" placeholder="Enter your E-mail here..."></div>
        <button id="email-submit"><b>SUBMIT E-MAIL TO RECEIVE LATEST NEWS</b></button>
      </form>
     </div>
  
</html>
```

Sorry this code is extremely long but I just posted whole thing so that you guys can have an easier time answering I guess.. The question is in the title, how do I prevent my enlarged container when hovered over container from overlapping my navigation bar like in picture below. I want it behind the navigation bar but still enlarged. The class that I'm doing the hover on is "enlarge" for easier finding. Thanks guys.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index#:%7E:text=The%20z%2Dindex%20CSS%20property,those%20with%20a%20smaller%20one.) to your `navbar` to make sure its not `overlapping` when `scrolling` and `hovering` over your `items`.

**Working Demo:**

```css
.normal {
  font-style: normal;
}

#intro-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 400px);
  grid-column-gap: 200px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  justify-content: center;
}

#header-image {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-column: 2/3;
}

#vid1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#vid2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
  top: 0;
  /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999999;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.navbar a {
  float: right;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 30px 30px;
}

body {
  background-color: #c19f97;
}

#intro {
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

#email-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

#video {
  text-align: center;
}

#email-input {
  width: 348px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#email-submit {
  background-color: #7e544b;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px 14px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#email-submit:hover {
  background: #c4a49c;
  transform: scale(1.02);
}

#features-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 400px 400px 400px;
  grid-column-gap: 200px;
  justify-content: center;
}

#delivery-truck-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 40px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-style: oblique;
}

#delivery-truck-container:hover {
  background: #d6c0ba;
}

#clothes-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 40px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-style: oblique;
}

#clothes-container:hover {
  background: #d6c0ba
}

#credit-card-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 40px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-style: oblique;
}

#credit-card-container:hover {
  background: #d6c0ba;
}

#delivery-truck {
  height: 200px;
}

#clothes {
  height: 200px;
}

#credit-card {
  height: 200px;
}

.enlarge:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div class="navbar" id="navigationbar">
  <a href="#Features">Features</a>
  <a href="#intro">Introduction</a>
  <a href="#prices">Prices</a> <br><br><br>
</div>

<div id="main-container">

  <h1 id="header">
    <center>Company name</center>
  </h1>
  <div id="intro-container">
    <div id="vid1"><iframe id="vid1" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/nSDgHBxUbVQ" width=300px height=300px></iframe></div>
    <div id="header-image"><img id="image1" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/circle-business-logo-company-name-260nw-626261534.jpg" alt="company-logo"></div>
    <div id="vid2"><iframe id="vid2" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YdYwICNPDwI" width=300px height=300px></iframe></div><br><br>
  </div>




  <center>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
  </center><br>
  <div id="features-container">

    <div class="enlarge" id="delivery-truck-container">
      <div id="delivery-truck-pic">
        <img class="pic" id="delivery-truck" src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Share/icon/ultraviolet/Ecommerce/delivery1600.png" alt="delivery-truck">
      </div>
      <div id="clothes-content">
        <center>
          <h1 class="normal">Lorem ipsum do</h1>
        </center>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="enlarge" id="clothes-container">
      <div id="clothes-pic">
        <img class="pic1" id="clothes" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/106/106020.png" alt="clothes">

      </div>
      <div id="clothes-content">
        <center>
          <h1 class="normal">Lorem ipsum do</h1>
        </center>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="enlarge" id="credit-card-container">
      <div class="pic" id="credit-card-pic">
        <img class="pic" id="credit-card" src="https://loanssos.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/credit-card.png" alt="credit-card">
      </div>
      <div id="credit-card-content">
        <center>
          <h1 class="normal">Lorem ipsum do</h1>
        </center>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <div id="email-container">
    <form action="https://www.freecodecamp.org/email-submit">
      <div id="email">
        <input id="email-input" type="email" placeholder="Enter your E-mail here..."></div>
      <button id="email-submit"><b>SUBMIT E-MAIL TO RECEIVE LATEST NEWS</b></button>
    </form>
  </div>

</html>
```